# Какой защититься при создании сервиса по сокращению ссылок?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

Оказалась нужна собственная реализация для сокращения ссылок для механизма "Поделиться ссылкой". Пользователь нажимает на кнопку, происходит передача данных на сервер, где генерируется случайная комбинация букв и цифр и записывается в Redis. Планирую реализовать это так: пользователь нажимает на кнопку, происходит POST-запрос на сервер, ссылка сохраняется, в клиент возвращается уникальный идентификатор ссылки, который копируется пользователю в буфер обмена.

С этим есть ряд проблем, которые нужно решить:

1. Сервис можно заабузить (слать большое количество рандомных ссылок
   POST-запросами и они будут складываться в Redis = в оперативную
   память)
2. При медленном интернете или при обрыве сети ссылка не будет сгенерирована.

Как наиболее подходящие пути решения этих проблем?

Comment: 1. Стандартные защиты от (D)DOS, начиная с банального fail2ban. 2. Забить.

Answer (score 0):

1) добавьте captcha, например от гугла https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html,
так же можно ограничить максимальное число запросов в единицу времени средствами веб-сервера.

2) если при медленном интернете или обрыве сети какие-то действия не произойдут - это нормально. пользователь попытается еще раз, когда скорость его сети восстановится.